# Is it possible to access an access database inside a query to a SQL server? (using C# and Queries)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to search in an access database in a query directed to a SQL server.

```
UPDATE [" + TableVariable + "] 
SET TK_Date = DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), TK_CA = TK_CA - 1 
WHERE TK_Date >= GETDATE()
AND TK_CA > 0 
AND TK_ResultCode in (SELECT Result_Code FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=C:\Users\Config.mdb].[Result_Code] 
WHERE Status = 2 
AND Project_ID = " + ProjectVariable + "
AND [" + TableVariable + "].TK_CA < [MS Access;DATABASE=C:\Users\Config.mdb].[Result_Code].TK_CA)
```

This is executed from a C# application.
the error i get is: Invalid object name 'MS Access;DATABASE=C:\Users.Config.mdb.Result_Code'

The variables are being filled in correctly and i have a connection to the databases aswell.

I tried a lot of combinations and searched on google for a couple of hours, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: you should look for Linked Servers - set up your Access DB as a linked server into your SQL server, only then you'll be able to query&join both (and not using the FROM [] you wrote above!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you have posted is for Access.

For SQL Server,  take a look at [`OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).